# Used by many people, yet so differently how

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Russian people use me intact.
> English people use me flipped.
> Bengali people use me hooked.
> Korean people use me shaved.
> Chinese people use me flipped and hooked.
> Japanese people use me flipped and stretched.

What am I?

Answer (score 4):

### Partial Answer

Disclaimer: I speak English, am native Chinese, know a lot of Japanese. However, I have no knowledge of Russian, Bengali or Korean.

You are

> The Russian letter Гг

Russian people use me intact.

> The Russians use this letter directly.

English people use me flipped.

> English has the letter "L", a flipped version thereof.

Bengali people use me hooked. **No idea.**

Korean people use me shaved. **No idea.**

Chinese people use me flipped and hooked.

> Chinese has a character 乚, which is Г and a hook added. One thing to note that this is an **ancient, archaic** Chinese character, and is not used at all in the modern language. It's the ancient form of the modern character 乙 meaning secondary. As a native I had to look it up in the dictionary to know its meaning.

Japanese people use me flipped and stretched.

> You could either be the hiragana く, the hiragana へ or the katakana　ヘ, all of which look like Г flipped (rotated) and stretched.

Comment: Rot13(Va Onatyn, gurer'f nyjnlf n yvar(-) ba gur gbc bs gur jbeqf naq yrggref juvpu pbhyq qrabgr ubbxrq. ল jbhyq or yrggre Y. Lbh pna frr gur vairegrq Y vf ubbxrq gb gur yvar ba gur gbc.)

Comment: You're on a right direction, yet parallel to the answer. Please keep going. (+1)